# Ex Manager shares Homophobic posts

Tags: management, work-environment, colleagues, human-resources, ethics

It's quite a lot that I wonder if I should do something or just be quiet.
So, one of me ex colleague from a previous job, that I have on facebook, shares all the time homophobic posts (honestly he seems a little bit too obsessed).

I don't work anymore in that company, meanwhile he also became a manager.
I wonder if I should take anyway some kind of actions, reaching my ex HR to make this comes out.

I feel I should, but on the other side I don't work there anymore. So I was wondering what you think.

Comment: Why exactly is this a workplace issue, given that you do not share a workplace?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a workplace issue.

Answer (score 4):

Unless he's directly causing or threatening harm to you or anyone else, mind your own business or take it up directly with him. Not his employer.

And if he is posing an obvious physical threat to you or anyone, then take it to the police. Not his employer.

Answer (score 3):

If these homophobic posts are of the "hate crime" variety (I support mass shootings of gays in a nightclub, I think all those fa***ts should burn, etc.) then report them straight to the police, and Facebook.

If they're of the "I have homophobic views" variety (I don't think gay people should be in the military, I don't think gay couples should adopt) then, AFAIK, those are just opinions that come under freedom of speech rather than anything legally enforceable. They're not very *nice* opinions - if it were me I'd block the guy, or keep tabs on him so I can make sure I don't end up working for him - but reporting to the police won't get you anywhere.

Whether you report the above to his HR department depends on your end game. If you really want to get him fired / disciplined in the hope that means he stops posting them, then sure, that's a strategy. Personally though I'd consider it none of my business, block him and move along.

Comment: "Freedom of speech" doesn't mean "Freedom of consequences", and companies don't like when something might put them under a bad light, including homophobic comments on social media from one of their managers.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself - do you believe in the value of free speech? Do you want people to only express thoughts and words that comply with what you are comfortable with?

Let's approach it a bit more mathematically - imagine the following scenario:
Let's say there are 5 topics: A, B, C, D, E. The opinions people express is one of the 5. Now imagine there are people who are offended by 0-4 of them. Let's say the distribution is equal (the amount of people offended by A are the same as those offended by A, B and the same as those offended by A, B, C).

That means: No matter what you express, some people will always be offended over something. If we'd ban everything that offends some people, we wouldn't be able to communicate anything of substance. Now comes the difference: Some people are more driven to cause harm to people who express A, B than D, E. Meaning most often when D is expressed, it gets a pass, while B is more likely to be picked up and reported.

For example I am a Libertarian, so for me anything advocating communism or socialism is offensive - because they indirectly imply I am wrong, while also further political agendas I consider bad. I am also offended by at least a hundred other things, including your idea to invoke cancel culture upon somebody for mere inappropriate comments on social media - because I could be the next put to the wall for having made an inappropriate comment or joke in the past. Luckily I avoid social media like the pest it is.

So in order to have communication, we have to acknowledge that 1. basically anything can be considered offensive, 2. being offended is not the exception but to be expected, possibly even the intention, and 3. that it can therefore not be a reason to censor. Being offensive is important for humor, but also to make political advancements against dogma and established rules which deserve criticism. Abolishing slavery was offensive as well, just as questioning a monarchy.

Now let's assume you'd succeed to cause your ex-colleague to be fired for that - is the consequence appropriate for the mere words made online? Remember that nowadays companies foolishly bend over backwards to appease social media activist mobs, just in order to be able to keep their reputation. This is mostly driven by what, ~1% of the population in the West active on social media and willing to partake in outrage/cancel culture to take out political opponents and offenders of so called "political correctness." Companies will act irrationally and this gives power to people who do as well. I consider this to be temporary, and companies who stand firm and resist the outrage ideology will prosper way more than those who bend the knee.

Besides that he, his job and well-being is none of your business (you could just as well stab him on the street and cause less damage to him overall, but I guess that does not feel so morally superior), what you consider to do is deeply authoritarian and against free speech. The very authoritarianism you'd contribute to would at some point backfire. And also consider that it's near certain you expressed offensive speech, which could also be brought up against you. This is a game everybody can lose (including yourself), and only few can win.

Find other ways to resolve your issue with him - how about you message him and ask him to stop, or simply accept the fact that people make "offensive" speeches ALL THE TIME including yourself.

Comment: Not saying I agree with the sentiments to close the question, but they did just prevent a potential nuclear war of comments going back and forth. I agree with you mostly on the grounds of free speech, but keeping this a more neutral ground might be in everyone's best interest.